# What is the largest number up to which all groups of that order and lower have been classified?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

As we all know, all finite simple groups have been classified up to isomorphism. As we also know the problem of classifying all groups up to isomorphism is "wild":

https://mathoverflow.net/questions/180355/in-what-sense-is-the-classification-of-all-finite-groups-impossible

Wikipedia gives a list of all finite groups up to order 30. What is the largest number up to which all groups of that order and lower have been classified?

Comment: So the answer to the question is $1023$.

Answer (score 0):

GAP has the "small groups library ", including info for groups up to order $2000$ (except  $1024$), cube free order $50000$ etc...  "List of small groups - Wikipedia" https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_small_groups